# Assertion Error while loading checkpoints in CPU

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to implement semantic segmentation of clothes using PSPNet and ResNet34. I am using the following Github repository for running: https://github.com/IanTaehoonYoo/semantic-segmentation-pytorch . However, I am getting the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joydipb01/Internships/Internship_Veybit/semantic-segmentation-pytorch/segmask.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/joydipb01/Internships/Internship_Veybit/semantic-segmentation-pytorch/segmask.py", line 33, in main
    logger.load_model(model, 'epoch_0')
  File "/home/joydipb01/Internships/Internship_Veybit/semantic-segmentation-pytorch/util/logger.py", line 227, in load_model
    assert Logger._exist(dir)
AssertionError
```

It is to be noted that I am loading the weights trained on GPU. Do I have to make changes to the load_model function in logger.py?

Comment: Issues regarding one specific repository could also be posted directly on GitHub in the "Issues" section. That way, other users of this repo will benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in line 226 of the logger.py function of the Github repository posted in the question. I did not have the path `./runs/models/{model_name}/{data_name}/epoch_0` in my system. A very silly mistake in the end!